# Issues getting my CSS transition to work

Tags: css

**Edit: I just applied the CSS to my website and it actually works. Apparently it was in the editor it was not. Not sure what the deal was, but it seems to work fine outside of the editor.**

I'm trying to create a custom checkbox based on the style here:http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp

I am trying to get the checkboxes background to transition when it is checked. However I am unable to get the transition to work, it just snaps right to the next color when checked.

```
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"] + label:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: 2px;
  width: 17px; height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-property: all;
}

/* Checked Transition */
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    background-color: #1ba8c4;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Add transition to the checked element too.

```
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    background-color: #1ba8c4;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-property: all;
}
```

It supposed to work. :)

Comment: I just applied the CSS to my website and it actually works. Apparently it was in the editor it was not. Not sure what the deal was, but it seems to work fine outside of the editor. 

Thanks for the reply though, I'm going to delete this question.